Error when creating Kubernetes Ingress resource (no matches for kind "Ingress")
In a cluster kubernetes environment I have Traefik v3.2.1 and CertManager 1.16.1 and a program I am testing.
when I try to apply this file: 022-red-ing.yml I get this error:
error: error validating "022-red-ing.yml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

I would like to define the file correctly but I am missing information since the documentation from where I copied it did not stated the apiVersion and kind.
The file is currently like this:

cat 022-red-ing.yml

   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    spec:
      selector:
        istio: ingressgateway
      servers:
      - hosts:
        - program.example.domain
        port:
          name: https
          number: 443
          protocol: HTTPS
        tls:
          credentialName: tls-program-ingress-http
          mode: SIMPLE
      - hosts:
        - program.example.domain
        port:
          name: program-frontend
          number: 80
          protocol: HTTP
        tls:
          httpsRedirect: true
      - hosts:
        - '*'
        port:
          name: http
          number: 80
          protocol: HTTP

what apiVersion and kind should I set?
If I prepend this code:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress

I get another error.
right now when I do:

kubectl apply -f 022-red-ing.yml

I get
error: error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses", GroupVersionKind: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Ingress"
Name: "", Namespace: "default"
from server for: "022-red-ing.yml": resource name may not be empty

I'm doing something wrong.

The Custom resource  definition (CRD) is a kubernetes resource that allows you to define a new resource type outside of kubernetes objects.Refer to this for more information on this. And the correct API version for Ingress is
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
   Kind: Ingress


Please refer to this link, which may help to resolve the issue.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your problem?

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If not I will be happy to assist you.

Your answer in the other question helped a lot. https://serverfault.com/questions/1168837/in-kubernetes-protect-a-program-that-runs-on-port-3000-using-traefik-cert-mana/1168840?noredirect=1#comment1530467_1168840 it seems that reinstalling traefik using the - - set ingressClass.enabled=true fixed the https


The file is currently like this...

I'm almost positive that it is not, because that file is not a valid Kubernetes manifest (it's missing the apiVersion, kind, and metadata sections).
From the error message (No matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"), it looks like you're using the incorrect apiVersion in the manifest. Instead of:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1

You need:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1

This is straight from the official documentation; it's not clear why you're using the wrong value, but it suggests you may be reading outdated material.

Thank you for your time. I edited the file adding your api version and kind: ingress. but I am getting this error: error: error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Resource=ingresses", GroupVersionKind: "networking.k8s.io/v1, Kind=Ingress"
Name: "", Namespace: "default"
from server for: "022-red-ing.yml": resource name may not be empty

It sounds like a syntax error in your manifest. Please update your question to show the exact manifest you're using.

oh, sorry, I edited the file adding the lines and posting it's output with cat. It's "censored" but the reason of the error might be intelligible.

It says, "resource name may not be empty", and I don't see the requried metadata section with the name.

I think my question is totally wrong then. because If I add metadata and name, now I get another error. and that makes me think the code I have it's not for an ingress. error is: kubectl apply -f 022-red-ing.yml
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "022-red-ing.yml": Ingress in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Ingress: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.selector", unknown field "spec.servers"
