In kubernetes: protect a program that runs on port 3000 using Traefik, Cert Manager, and http challenge
Hello and thank you for your time. I will try to explain what is my experiment.
In kubernetes I have an app deployed. I can reach it with a load balancer. And using traefik I can reach it via http. I would like to reach it via Https. To achieve that result I am attempting to follow youtube videos and traefik documentation and use cert manager.
I like to work using yml files, but if there is a better way please tell me, since I am learning from practice.
I will post all the theoretically yml files hoping that serverfault give me space enough to publish them.
#001-role.yml
        kind: ClusterRole
    apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    metadata:
      name: traefik-role
    
    rules:
      - apiGroups:
          - ""
        resources:
          - services
          - secrets
          - nodes
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - discovery.k8s.io
        resources:
          - endpointslices
        verbs:
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - extensions
          - networking.k8s.io
        resources:
          - ingresses
          - ingressclasses
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch
      - apiGroups:
          - extensions
          - networking.k8s.io
        resources:
          - ingresses/status
        verbs:
          - update
      - apiGroups:
          - traefik.io
        resources:
          - middlewares
          - middlewaretcps
          - ingressroutes
          - traefikservices
          - ingressroutetcps
          - ingressrouteudps
          - tlsoptions
          - tlsstores
          - serverstransports
          - serverstransporttcps
        verbs:
          - get
          - list
          - watch

#002-account.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: traefik-account

#003-role-binding.yml
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: traefik-account
    namespace: default 

#004-traefik.yml
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: traefik-deployment
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: traefik-account
      containers:
        - name: traefik
          image: traefik:v3.2
          args:
            - --api.insecure
            - --providers.kubernetesingress
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
            - name: dashboard
              containerPort: 8080

#005-traefik-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: dashboard
  selector:
    app: traefik
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - targetPort: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: traefik

#006-program-frontend-deployment.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: program-frontend
  name: program-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: program-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: program-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - env:
            - name: API_GATEWAY_BASE_URL
              value: http://edge-thinghy:9000
          image: program-image
          name: program-frontend
          ports:
            -  name: program-frontend
               containerPort: 3000
               protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ghcr-secret
      restartPolicy: Always

#007-program-frontend-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.34.0 (HEAD)
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: program-frontend
  name: program-frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - name: program-frontend
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: program-frontend
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: program-frontend

#008-edit-program-service.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: program-frontend
spec:
  ports:
    - name: program-frontend
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: program-frontend

#009-program-ingress.yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: program-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: program-frontend
            port: 
              name: program-frontend

#010-challenge.yml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
 name: program-challenge
 namespace: default
spec:
 acme:
   email: my-mail@my.domain
   server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
   privateKeySecretRef:
     name: program-issuer-account-key
   solvers:
     - http01:
         ingress:
           class: traefik

#011-ingress-rule.yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: program-ssl-ingress
 namespace: default
 annotations:
   cert-manager.io/issuer: "program-challenge"
spec:
 tls:
   - hosts:
       - program-demo.example.domain
     secretName: tls-program-ingress-http
 rules:
   - host: program-demo.example.domain
     http:
       paths:
         - path: /
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: program-frontend
               port:
                 name: program-frontend

#012-redirect-http-to-https.yml
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: program-frontend-redirect
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true

If I understood correctly, at that point I should be able to reach https://program-demo.example.domain but I am reaching only http://program-demo.example.domain did I misread something in the documentation? Is something wrong in my reasoning? Thank you for your time in advance.

For setting up the HTTPS for your kubernetes app using traefik as the Ingress controller and Cert manager for automatic SSL certificate you can try installing helm chart  which is a package manager for kubernetes). Below is the example, how to install it.
helm repo add traefik
https://helm.traefik.io/traefik
helm install traefik traefik/traefik 
- - set ingressClass.enabled=true

As per this documentation , When a TLS section is included, Traefik is told that the router is only going to handle HTTPS requests and that HTTP (non-TLS) requests should be ignored. In order to provide decrypted data to the services, Traefik will stop using the SSL connections.
Additionally, go through this community link which will be helpful for your issue.

hello and thank you for your time. I already installed with helm traefik but did not specify set ingress.class.enabled=true. my command was, helm install traefik traefik/traefik
should I uninstall and reinstall? also, the post on the community is made by me, but still didn't got a lot of support.

Absolutely, could you try reinstalling it and using the command that was mentioned to check it?

Also have you gone through the documentation which I have shared and please let us know if you have followed the same.

hello, sadly that documentation is not for version 3.2.1 of Traefik

Have you checked this migration guide and also this version of update adds only optional fields.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

thank you. I am double-checking it. originally I followed this article: https://traefik.io/blog/secure-web-applications-with-traefik-proxy-cert-manager-and-lets-encrypt/ but I ended having the certificate, and traefik installed acting as a proxy only for http.

I am attempting to understand how it works here https://community.traefik.io/t/have-i-understood-correctly-how-to-protect-a-program-in-kubernetes-with-traefik/25543

it seems that your answer is right, after reinstalling with helm and the flag you suggested it is working now.
